# Big O Notation Simplification

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

So I'm trying to learn how to simplify Big O notations, these are the ones i'm working on (also sorry if i mess up the format, i'm new)

**So the first one i have is:
f(n) = n    g(n) = n/loglog 12**

I have to determine whether f is O(g), Omega(g), or Theta(g).

I also want to account for Big O vs Little O (which is also something i'm having trouble understanding but i think the idea is simply strictly greater than or strictly less than).

How i simplified:
f(n) = n, g(n) = n/loglog12 -> g(n) = n
f is Theta(g) ?? since simplified it is, f(n) = n and g(n) = n?

Am i doing this right?

Comment: No, you're not doing it right. $g(n)=n/\log\log12$ does not imply that $g(n)=n$, as you claim.

Comment: You're on the right track, but your approach is messy. Maybe write down the definition of big-O and see if you can prove whether or not f is big-O of g, using the exact definition.